# Angular Universal - NodeJS Server's Response to HTML for Dynamic Routes

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

In angular-universal **Tour of Heroes** application (https://angular.io/generated/zips/universal/universal.zip) , we can use `prerender` script to generate static HTML for `static routes` only. Is there any way to print the generated HTML on NodeJS console in case of `dynamic routes`:

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
});
```

What changes I need to do here if I want to print the generated HTML on console for the route :

```
http://localhost:4000/detail/12
```

Does this require other node js libraries ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a callback to the `render` method

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: 
APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] }, (err, html)=> console.log(html));
});
```

See the documentation here

https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.render